# Using xpath to select a value based on another elements value

Tags: xml, xpath

I'm looking to extract `8` from below piece of `XML` based on either `Shoe Size` or `MenShoesShoe Size` using `XPATH`.
I've tried some variations but I can only select individual values i.e `8`.
 
And the whitespace is causing issues too, can anyone be of help please?
Of coarse, the whole `XML` contains many colors and sizes so I'd be looking for `all` sizes.

```
<Entry> 
  <Attributes> 
    <Values> 
      <values>Tan</values>  
      <identifier>Tan</identifier>  
    </Values>  
    <identifier>MenShoesColor</identifier>  
    <name>Color</name>  
  </Attributes>  
  <Attributes> 
    <Values> 
      <values>8</values>  
      <identifier>8</identifier>  
    </Values>  
    <identifier>MenShoesShoe Size</identifier>  
    <name>Shoe Size</name>  
  </Attributes> 
</Entry>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for

```
//Entry/Attributes[identifier = 'MenShoesShoe Size' or name = 'Shoe Size' ]/Values/values/text()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you meant to get values of `<Attributes>` having "MenShoesShoe Size" identifier or having "Shoe Size" name, then you can try this way (formatted for readability) :

```
/Entry
/Attributes[indentifier='MenShoesShoe Size' or name='Shoe Size']
/Values
/value
```